# Trying to get the area of a rectangle using python 3.7

Tags: python

Instructions:  This function to calculate the area of a rectangle is not very readable. Can you refactor it, and then call the function to calculate the area with base of 5 and height of 6?
Tip: a function that calculates the area of a rectangle should probably be called rectangle_area, and if it's receiving base and height, that's what the parameters should be called.

My attempt:

```
def area_rectangle (base, height):
    area_rectangle (5, 6)
    area = (base*height)

    print("The area is " + str(area))
```

Error message:

Here is your output:

Not quite. Remember to use meaningful names for functions
and variables, and to call the function correctly.

Question:  What am I doing incorrectly, to rectify this issue?

Comment: You're calling the function recursively and not returning anything

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you meant:

```
def area_rectangle (base, height):
    area = (base * height)
    print("The area is " + str(area))
area_rectangle(5, 6)
```

The reason your code didn't work is because it will become infinite recursion. The function would call itself and call itself infinite times until the `RecursionError` comes.

So you would need to call it outside the function.